Why can't I compile C from the Linux command line?
I run Linux Mint and I am trying to compile a .c file from the command line using the gcc command. However, when I do so, I get an error message that says stdio.h doesnt exist.
I tried gcc filename.c -o test and expected the creation of an executable file named "test" that I could then run.

Please provide your code. We can't help you without any code.

glibc is probably not installed on your system. Try installing the build-essential package, e.g., sudo apt install build-essential.

It is working now.

Unrelated note (this is not the cause of the error. Just  a likely cause of the next one): avoid calling your program test, since it is the name of a standard unix command (as long as you run your code with ./test, no problem. But when you'll try to store it in the PATH, you will risk some confusions)
